# Opening a new tab with clipboard contents as a variable?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I will have a geographic coordinates in my clipboard and wish to open a google maps link with those coordinates. I am trying to create either a bookmarklet or a script that is triggered by a keyboard shortcut.

I was trying to turn this into a bookmarklet but was not sure where I was messing up.

```
coords = window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
window.open('https://google.com/maps/search/${coords}', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This can be done using `navigator`

```
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(
        clipText => window.open(
            'https://google.com/maps/search/'+clipText, '_blank'
        )
    );
```